# How do I eliminate extra vertical space between the title and the first section heading?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, amsart

When I use the `amsart` class with a lot of in-text figures, I find that the section headings do not stand out quite as much as I would like. Thus, I have taken to adding the following to my preamble, which adds a extra vertical space before each section heading:

```
\let \oldsection \section
\renewcommand{\section}{\vspace{8pt plus 3pt}\oldsection}
```

This works well for me, except when I have a section heading right after the document title; in this case, I find would prefer that no extra space be added.

**How can I eliminate this extra space "automatically"--i.e., without explicitly adjusting spacing in the body of the document?**

---

**Examples:**

Here are three examples side-by-side:
[image]

You may want to [zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opSWF.png).

The example on the left is the result of the code below:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\let \oldsection \section
\renewcommand{\section}{\vspace{8pt plus 3pt}\oldsection}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Random title}
\author{Fred P.~Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The first section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The next section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]
Notice the extra space after "Fred P. Author" compared to the result I would like (the image on the right, in the side-by-side picture):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Random title}
\author{Fred P.~Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The first section}
\lipsum[2]
\vspace{8pt plus 3pt}
\section{The next section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, the image in the middle was given simply to illustrate that the `titlesec` package does not seem to solve the problem--at least, not in any naively obvious way. The code I used for it was the following (which I do not claim is exactly equivalent, but which still demonstrates the same extra space after the document title/author):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\scshape\filcenter}
  {\thesection.}
  {1ex}
  {}
\titlespacing{\section}
  {0pt}{18pt}{6pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Random title}
\author{Fred P.~Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The first section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The next section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `\addvspace` instead of `\vspace` in the redefinition of `\section`.  if the previous element ends with vertical space, this should check the amount, and add only enough space to yield the larger of the original or the added amount.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: When I change `\vspace` to `\addvspace`, it gets rid of the additional space everywhere. If I increase the value enough to have an effect, it gives the same extra space after `\maketitle`.

Comment: Note: The real question here, for me, may be, "Can it be set up so that `\vspace` right after `\maketitle` gets eliminated, much as `\vspace` at the top of a page does?"

Comment: very peculiar.  the space before the second section shouldn't be decreased, but you're correct, it is.  i will try to figure out why.

Comment: have you looked at the `titling` package?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't redefine `\section` like that, but use the standard method. If you're *sure* that your document starts with a section title, use

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\amsartsection{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{2.5\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
\def\section{\vspace*{-34pt}\vspace{\baselineskip}\let\section\amsartsection\section}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Random title}
\author{Fred P.~Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The first section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The next section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

The `\maketitle` command adds 34pt space minus the value of `\baselineskip`. Adjust the multiples of `\linespacing` used in the definition of `\amsartsection` (which is the definition of `\section` that will be actually used in the document).

Comment: I think this is helpful. At the same time, I would point out that at my current level of TeX knowledge, the code block you are using is largely incomprehensible to me (as are most things involving `@`); so I have absolutely no chance of applying, on my own, this mythical "standard method" to which you refer.

Comment: Nevertheless, it looks to me as if the key point your answer is not so much the use of `\amsartsection`, as the fact that the `\section` macro incorporates a redefinition of itself, so that it will behave differently after the first time it is used. This is a hack (I would like a solution that works even when I am *not* sure the document starts with a section title), but (arguably) an improvement on inserting a `\vspace*{`negative length`}` before an initial `\section` command.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Actually, on second thought, I believe that adding a negative spacing is just the right thing to do. I guess that adding some conditionals could automatically solve the problem; but this is probably a false problem: how many articles are you writing? :)

Comment: I'm using this for lecture notes that I pass out to my students. I give three lectures per week, at an institution that has three ten-week quarters in a standard academic year. So, I'm using this for about ninety documents per academic year. And I'd like to be able to reorder sections without worrying about spacing.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work, so far as I can tell. When `\maketitle` is immediately followed by a `\section` (or `\section*`) command, some negative space is added immediately after `\maketitle`.

However, there are a few easy ways to break it--for instance, skipping a line between `\maketitle` and the first `\section` command, or (I assume) putting a `\comment` in the same place (or a `\newcommand` or any other command that would not normally affect the layout when placed there).

Additional note: If the `hyperref` package is used with this hack, the `hyperref` package should be loaded *first*.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\let \oldsection \section
\def \newsection {\vspace{8pt plus 3pt}\oldsection}
\renewcommand{\section}{\newsection}

\let \oldmaketitle = \maketitle
\def \newmaketitle {\oldmaketitle \vspace*{-34pt}\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\def \titleDecide {%
    \ifx \nextToken \section
        \let \next = \newmaketitle
    \else
        \let \next = \oldmaketitle
    \fi
    \next
}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\futurelet \nextToken \titleDecide}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Random title}
\author{Fred P.~Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{The first section}
\lipsum[2]
\section{The next section}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very far from being bullet-proof to empty line after `\maketitle`, which is what most people who tidy their code do. You could check for `\par` first and throw it away if present, but what if I put `\newcommand` after `\maketitle`? It is a nice idea, but as **barbara** suggests above, this needs investigation of `amsart` and proper correction of how spacing is coded there.

Comment: @tohecz: As I say in the answer itself, it breaks quite easily. But as long as I know to make sure that e.g. any empty line after `\maketitle` starts with `%`, it should serve my purposes. And since this answer already took me well beyond the previous boundaries of my TeX knowledge, I will have to leave any further investigations of the sort you suggest up to others, at least for the time being.